# How to run all tests in a particular package with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, junit

I can find in the [Maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html) where it shows how to run:

1. A single test
2. All tests in a single test class
3. All tests in classes matching a particular pattern

But how to run all the tests in a package? Is this possible?

I would prefer solutions that don't require modifying the `pom.xml` or code.

Comment: try this [link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

Comment: If you are using intellij, just select the package in the project window and do "Ctrl+Shift+F10". I know this is not directly using the maven but I hope will be helpful to someone out there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5687711/im-bhatman  - nice one

Answer (score 238, accepted):

You could use a pattern as well, for example

```
 mvn '-Dtest=de.mypackage.*Test' test
```

runs all tests in classes from package *de.mypackage* ending on `*Test`.

[update 2017/12/18]:
Since this became the accepted answer, here's some further information:

- Maven uses the [Maven Surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html) to execute tests.
- The syntax used above (qualified package name) requires Surefire version `2.19.1` or higher! Earlier versions require the use of path expressions, for example

  ```
  mvn -Dtest="de/mypackage/*Test" test
  ```
- I'm using quotes (` or ") to prevent the shell from performing pathname expansion, Maven doesn't require any quotes.
- A single test method can be exuted using the following syntax

  ```
  mvn -Dtest=MyUnitTest#testMethod test
  ```
- All tests from subpackages may be includes as well, in order to execute all tests in or beneath package `de.mypackage.sub` execute:

  ```
  mvn -Dtest="de/mypackage/sub/**" test
  ```

  or with Surefire `2.19.1` or higher

  ```
  mvn -Dtest="de.mypackage.sub.**" test
  ```

There are further possibilities like using regular expressions, see the [official documentation of running a single test](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html).

Comment: Worked perfectly for me!  mvn test -Dtest=com.example.handler.*Test

Comment: You can even do `mvn '-Dtest=de.mypackage.**.*Test' test` to include subpackages

Comment: In Maven 3 it works fine when I don't use apostrophe (')

Comment: When you want to test many packages, You can list it all (just write all of them after comma), e.g.: `mvn -Dtest=com.packadmin.*Test,com.packclient.*Test test`

Comment: surefire version < 2.19.1, `mvn -Dtest="de/mypackage/*Test" test` is the right stuff.  Thanks!

Comment: For anyone else trying to run tests within a package you have to end with `**.*`. Ex. `-Dtest="com.name.**.*"`

Comment: on my Mac it worked only with backticks: `-Dtest=\`de/mypackage/*Test\``
  it didn't work with quotation marks ("), apostrophes('), or without it

Comment: be sure to add `-DfailIfNoTests=false` when using running `mvn test` with the `-Dtest` property in a multi-module project's root, or the tests with fail if maven doesn't find a match in one of the submodules.

Comment: Is interesting that neither `mvn test '-Dtest=de.mypackage'` nor `mvn test '-Dtest=de.mypackage.*'`  do **not** work - of course `mvn test '-Dtest=de.mypackage.*Tests'`  works as indicated

Answer (score 25):

AFAIK there are no command line parameter for surefire:test to run tests in a specific package.

I use a configuration variable to achieve the same effect. A fragment of my pom.xml:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/${testGroup}/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now if I want to run tests in a package named "com.example", I use the following command:

```
mvn test -DtestGroup=com/example
```

Answer (score 23):

You can take reference from the following scenarios:

(1) Skip all test execution during maven build

```
mvn package -DskipTests
```

(2) Execute All test cases

```
mvn test
```

(3) Execute specific test group

```
mvn test -DincludeGroups=TestGroup1,TestGroup2
```

(4) Exclude specific test group during execution

```
mvn test -DexcludeGroups=TestGroup3,TestGroup4
```

(5) Execute specific package testcases

```
mvn test -Dtest="com.service.map.**"
```

(6) Execute specific test

```
mvn test -Dtest=Test1,Test2
```

I hope it will be more helpful to you with a different combination of execution.

Answer (score 10):

```
mvn test -Dtest=com.myrootpackage.myfirstlevelpackage.*
```

...and if you want to include all sub packages:

```
mvn test -Dtest=com.myrootpackage.myfirstlevelpackage.**.*
```

Comment: The former does **not** work, it must be `mvn test -Dtest=com.myrootpackage.myfirstlevelpackage.*Tests` - the latter works fine, but is not necessary the latest `.*` part

Answer (score 5):

The pom.xml version of O Badr's answer:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                 <!-- includes all tests, but not in subpackages -->
                        <include>**/package1/*</include>   
                 <!-- includes all tests, AND in subpackages -->
                        <include>**/package2/**</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: My old questions about Maven get views pretty consistently ... I'm not sure whether I should be happy or sad about that.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem (how to run all tests in a particular package) and tried many ways, two commands that worked were:

```
mvn -Dtest=com.package.my.package.** test

mvn -Dtest=com.package.my.package.**.* test
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best answer, but you could run a single TestSuite (which is a Test) which includes all the test you want in one package.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done by

```
mvn clean test -Dtest="**/service/**/*.java"
```

eg: I am in my /home/repository and I want to run tests on /home/repository/service folder only

Here service folder is inside my current folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can mention packages in your pom.xml through Surefire-plugin

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>com.mycom.mydep.mypak.*, com.mycom.mydep.mypak2.*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Please note that JUnit version should be greater than 4.8. and version of surefire should be 2.19.1
[Find more details here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)