# spring boot multiple tests classes but only is executed when mvn package the app

Tags: spring-boot, maven, junit

I have fresh spring boot application generated from https://start.spring.io/

My problem is the generated already Test class is the only one is executed even when I have added different test classes with the same **annotaions** as the generated one and **located in the same package**.

spring boot version is : 2.2.4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to run all tests in a particular package with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819888/how-to-run-all-tests-in-a-particular-package-with-maven)

Comment: Is not it the default behaviour that all test classes in the same package to be executed? I just want to run all classes without exclusions or inclusions.

Comment: can you mention the annotations and class declaration of your test class? e.g which other class it extends?

Comment: typical spring boot generated application from spring intializer.The answer provided by JARgente below is correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem could be because of the name of the test classes.
By default maven only executes test in the clasees which follows this name convention: (In short the test class must starts or ends with Test word)

By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:

> "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>   filenames that start with "Test". "**/*Test.java" - includes all of
>   its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
>   "**/*Tests.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>   filenames that end with "Tests". "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of
>   its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".

As you can see in

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html