# TestNG's @Test annotation not executed properly with the mvn command

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng

Everything with the @Test annotation throws null pointer exception, regardless of the method called. I tried calling driver.findElement() and executing js script with JavascriptExecutor. Both methods ended up with a null pointer.
If I run through the IDE everything works like a charm. Otherwise, only the Before and After annotations are executed adequately
Here's my pom.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <threadCount>1</threadCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache-extras.beanshell</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        <version>2.0b6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

 </project>
```

and testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Practice Suite">
<test name="Test Basics 1">

    <method-selectors>
        <method-selector>
            <script language="beanshell">
                <![CDATA[
                String testGroup = System.getProperty("env");
                groups.containsKey(testGroup);
            ]]>
            </script>
        </method-selector>
    </method-selectors>
    
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.SignUpTest"/>
    </classes>
</test>

 </suite>
```

and finally the two manners I am using to run the test:

`mvn -Dwebdriver=chrome -Denv=qa install`

`mvn -Dwebdriver=chrome -Denv=qa test`

EDIT:

BeforeTest and Test:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class BaseTest {


protected  WebDriver driver;

private WebDriver selectDriver(String driver)

    switch (driverString) {
        case "chrome":
            return new ChromeDriver();
        case "firefox":
            return new FirefoxDriver();
        case "edge":
            return new EdgeDriver();
        case "safari":
            return new SafariDriver();
        default:
            return new ChromeDriver();
    }
    
}

     @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public void testInit() {

        driver = selectDriver(System.getProperty("webdriver"));

    }

}

import additions.BaseTest;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import pages.DashBoardPage;
import pages.LoginPage;


public class LoginTest extends BaseTest {

@Test
public void successfulLogin(){
    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);

    loginPage
            .populateUserName("somename")
            .populatePassword("somepassowrd")
            .clickLoginButton();

}
```

}

Comment: Please upgrade the version of `maven-surefire-plugin` because it's an ancient version at minimum 2.22.2 ...

Comment: Done, but the issue still persists.

Comment: I have a clue. It appears that the Test annotation is executed before the BeforeTest one.

Comment: Please show a test case....

Comment: I have edited my post. Please have a look. I tried to make it tidier than it is. Hope it is readable

Comment: Yes but unfortunately you have omitted the import statements.. please add them..

Comment: I've made another edit with the imports

Answer (score 1):

Since still there is some uncertainty in the question, I'll try to share my thoughts around this.

> If I run through the IDE everything works like a charm.

There are several ways how to run this in IDE:

1. Run the test class.

   In this case IDE generates own `testng.xml` which not match the example (from the question), so it will not contain any `method-selector` items.
2. Run the testng.xml

   In `testng.xml` there is `method-selector` which expects `System.getProperty("env")` provided.
   If you run testng.xml from IDE, you have to provide somehow
   `System.getProperty("env")` via IDE settings, otherwise you'll see `org.testng.TestNGException: javax.script.ScriptException` error.

---

If I look at `testng.xml`, I see `method-selector`, which filter tests by `System.getProperty("env")`.

And If I look at the test:

```
@Test
public void successfulLogin(){
    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
```

I see no any group defined for it. So this test **cannot be executed** with maven command. And it's unclear how it might throw any exception.

---

If I look at maven command

```
mvn -Dwebdriver=chrome -Denv=qa test
```

I cannot see the arg defining which testng xml suite to execute.

I expect the command like:

```
mvn test -Dwebdriver=chrome -Denv=qa -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles="src/test/resources/tests.xml"
```

---

**Expected behavior**

When we execute the maven command:

```
mvn test -Dwebdriver=chrome -Denv=qa -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles="src/test/resources/tests.xml"
```

method-selector in testng.xml looks for methods matching the `qa` group.

and *there are no any methods, matched this group*.

But there are some configuration methods with `alwaysRun = true`, and *they will be executed anyway*.

So

```
 @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public void testInit() {
```

is invoked without any tests,

and the output will be:

```
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.345 s - in TestSuite
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.867 s
```

And the test will be executed if we'll add the group:

```
@Test(groups= {"qa"})
public void successfulLogin(){
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I Actually do have groups with "qa" and they work when running the testng.xml file using the IDE. On Monday I will try to fix it with the information from your answer and I will update you. Thanks again.

Comment: I pass the -Dwebdriver and -Denv in the VM options field from the configuration window of IntelliJ. From the same window, I changed the Test kind to "Suite" and now the build fails even from the IDE. Have in mind that I set the full path to the suite, but it still fails. I guess this is yet another clue. I will try to fix it, but if you come up with solution, please let me know.

Comment: Actually this worked for me:
`mvn test -Dwebdriver=chrome -Denv=qa -Dtest=SignUpTest.java`
Now I am trying to figure out how to do it for a package and not for a single test class.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819888/how-to-run-all-tests-in-a-particular-package-with-maven

Comment: Still doesn't work, but I will deal with it. Thanks everyone for the great help

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. It turns out that initialising the driver with the @BeforeTest annotation is not a good idea, especially if your teardown method is marked with @AfterTest. The driver is initialised and used correctly in the first @Test method, but on the second one, the teardown method is already called and the driver becomes null. So I used @BeforeClass and @AfterClass (I might reconsider and use @Before/AfterSuite). Then I added the following configuration to the  pom.xml

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
             
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then I added the package with the tests I wanted to execute, in the testng.xml file, like this:

```
        <packages>
        <package name="path.to.tests.*"></package>
    </packages>
```

Finally I called the mvn command using the following syntax:

```
mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng.xml  -Dwebdriver="chrome" -Denv="qa"
```

This way you don't have to call the path to the testng.xml file, but rather call it out of the pom.xml. As a side note to the last sentence, my testng.xml file is located in the project directory, along with the src folder. If you put it in another folder, I guess it will be good to set the path to this folder in the pom.xml

I hope this is understandable and it will be helpful for anyone who gets stuck with such issue.

Thank again to the others for the clues.