# Trying to run tests in a java package using Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit

Following this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819888/how-to-run-all-tests-in-a-particular-package-with-maven). I have a test class at
`~/IdeaProjects/mavenproject1/src/test/java/FirstPackage/EmployeeTest.java` which looks like below

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.Test;

public class EmployeeTest extends TestCase{
    Employee e = new Employee();

    @Test
    public void testSayNothing() {
        assertEquals("hello",e.getEmployee("hello"));
    }
}
```

How do I run all tests in this package `FirstPackage`
The below command fails
`mvn '-Dtest=FirstPackage.*' test` with the error:

```
INFO] --- surefire:3.1.2:test (default-test) @ codebase1 ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.971 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-16T15:49:43-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.1.2:test (default-test) on project codebase1: No tests matching pattern "FirstPackage.*" were executed! (Set -Dsurefire.failIfNoSpecifiedTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: The class is missing a [`package` declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html) that matches the directory structure